# ReflectionCache Serializable exception

Tags: kotlin, apache-beam

Long history short, I have developed a pipeline using apache beam + dataflow in Java and everything was working as expected.
Couple of weeks ago I started to convert my java code to kotlin it's when I started to see this problem.

Code Sample:

```
private val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
// read json file
  val lines = pipeline.apply("Reading Input Data ", TextIO.read().from(options.inputFile))

    // parse json
 val exchangeObject = lines.apply("Convert Data to ExchangeObject model data", ParseJsons.of(ExchangeObject::class.java).withMapper(objectMapper)).setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(ExchangeObject::class.java))
```

When the code tries to parse the Json is when the code failed with:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.ReflectionCache
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the issue from https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/245.

This is related to Apache Beam for one reason: lambdas are serialized so they can be run on a distributed system. The recommendation is to make it transient and then re-create it. Beam's Jackson extension has the `ParseJsons` transform that does not follow this practice.